# How to send multiple JSON objects through a URLConnection?

Tags: android, json, urlencode

I'm new to Android. In this method, I'm willing to send a BEAccident object along with some Strings, but the server throws an error.

public String SendAccident(BEAccident accident, String username,
            String password) {

```
    JSONObject jsonAccident = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonAccident.put("HasDocuments", accident.getHasDocuments());
        jsonAccident.put("ChassisNumber", accident.getChassisNumber());
        jsonAccident.put("ContainerNumber", accident.getContainerNumber());
        jsonAccident.put("Description", accident.getDescription());
        jsonAccident.put("IdTMUser", accident.getIdTMUser());
        jsonAccident.put("LicensePlate", accident.getLicensePlate());
        jsonAccident.put("LocalDateTime", accident.getLocalDateTime());
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        return e1.getMessage();
    }

    try{
        // Set Request parameter
        data +="&" + URLEncoder.encode("Username", "UTF-8") + "="+username;
        data +="&" + URLEncoder.encode("Password", "UTF-8") + "="+password;
        data +="&" + URLEncoder.encode("LoadNumber", "UTF-8") + "="+"LN0003";
        data +="&" + URLEncoder.encode("Accident", "UTF-8") + "="+URLEncoder.encode(jsonAccident.toString(), "UTF-8");

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    // Send data
    try {

        URL url = new URL(URL_SEND_ACCIDENT);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(
                conn.getOutputStream());

        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();

        // Get the server response

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        // Read Server Response
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Append server response in string
            sb.append(line + "");
        }

        // Append Server Response To Content String
        Content = sb.toString();
        return Content;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Error = ex.getMessage();
        return Error;
    } finally {
        try {

            reader.close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

Please advise if this is the right way to send a non-native object using URLConnection. I appreciate any response.

Comment: can you show the code on the server side?

Comment: @NagyVilmos I'm afraid it is not available. All I know is that it works perfectly in iOS. Thanks.

Comment: try to replace your ` data +="&" + URLEncoder.encode("Accident", "UTF-8") + "="+URLEncoder.encode(jsonAccident.toString(), "UTF-8");` this line with

` data +="&" + URLEncoder.encode("Accident", "UTF-8") + "="+jsonAccident.toString();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work with the following approach:

```
public String SendAccident(BEAccident accident, String username,
        String password) {

    JSONObject jsonAccident = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject parameter = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonAccident.put("HasDocuments", accident.getHasDocuments());
        jsonAccident.put("ChassisNumber", accident.getChassisNumber());
        jsonAccident.put("ContainerNumber", accident.getContainerNumber());
        jsonAccident.put("Description", accident.getDescription());
        jsonAccident.put("IdTMUser", 1);
        jsonAccident.put("LicensePlate", accident.getLicensePlate());
        jsonAccident.put("LocalDateTime", accident.getLocalDateTime());


        parameter.put("Username", username);
        parameter.put("Password", password);
        parameter.put("LoadNumber", accident.getLoadNumber());
        parameter.put("Accident", jsonAccident);
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
        return e1.getMessage();
    }

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); // Timeout
                                                                            // Limit
    HttpResponse response;

    try {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL_SEND_ACCIDENT);


        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(parameter.toString());

        post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");


        post.setEntity(se);


        response = client.execute(post);
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        /* Checking response */
        if (response != null) {
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); // Get the
                                                                // data in
                                                                // the
                                                                // entity
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            // Read Server Response
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Append server response in string
                sb.append(line + "");
            }

            // Append Server Response To Content String
            Content = sb.toString();
            return Content;

        }
        return "Response is null";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

This can occur if parameter names in your query string do not match with the web service's parameter names. it would be helpful if you can state what kind of server you are receiving.

Comment: Yeah, that was my first guess. (Un)fortunately the names are good.